# What about Ubuntu 12.04 core updates every 6 months?

Tags: updates, ati, fglrx, lts

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is supported for 5 years, and will get some core updates for 2 years : I guess those updates include the kernel, graphic drivers and X11.

But will these updates be optionnal, or not ?

I would like to stick with my present version of the kernel and X11, because I'm using an AMD/ATI graphic card with fglrx driver, but according to this [link](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amd_catalyst_legacy2&num=1), support for ATI HD 2000/3000/4000 cards will be dropped soon.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the update-manager client you can just unselect the update that you don't want to install. I haven't updated my kernel for some time because of a problem with the laptop screen brightness that I don't want to fix every time.

the other option is to put those packages on hold. I havent done this in a long time and not in Ubuntu, but there [is a guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html) for Debian. check chapter 7.12.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. However, I don't like this solution pretty much :/ I would like to keep with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for 2 years, and unselecting the kernel and X11 updates from update-manage is not recommended. I would like to know if kernel 3.2 and Xorg 1.11 will still be maintained by Canonical after the first "core release", probably in October.

Comment: I added another possibility, that might be more useful for you.